# О зарплатах пожарных или о зарплате пожарных? Какой вариант верен?

Tags: склонение

О зарплатах пожарных или о зарплате пожарных.....Имеется ввиду множественное число в контексте: Начальник пожарной службы в интервью рассказал о том-то....и о зарплате (ах) пожарных.

Answer (score 2):

Начальник пожарной службы в интервью рассказал о том-то....**и о зарплате** пожарных.

В данном случае **используется ед. число:** начальник мог  **раскрыть тему зарплаты** в разных аспектах (общий уровень, максимальная, минимальная, средняя).

Слово имеет две формы, и каждый раз надо выбирать нужную **по смыслу, а не по правилу.**

**Примеры**:

С 1 января 2017 года **зарплаты** управленческого персонала государственных и муниципальных учреждений должны увязываться со **среднемесячной зарплатой** остальных сотрудников и подчиняться предельным соотношениям, установленным органами-учредителями.

В первом случае речь идет о различных учреждениях, о различном управленческом персонале, поэтому используется мн. число. А среднемесячная зарплата - это ед. число.

Власти Московской области в течение 2017 года дважды повысят **зарплату** бюджетникам.  Рассматривается определенная категория работников, речь идет об общем уровне оплты труда.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, оба варианта верны, но первый (о зарплатах пожарных) подчеркавает, что зарплаты разные, а второй - более общий (то же, что об оплате труда пожарных). Начальник мог говорить о разных зарплатах или в общем о зарплате

Comment: а какое это правило?

Comment: Не думаю, что есть формальные правила на этот счет (а может,  они мне не известны).